# Cocos2d Rocking Animation with CCRotateBy?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccrotateby

I'm new to Cocos2d and am after some help.

I have a sprite that I want to rotate 45 degrees to the left, center itself again and then rotate about 45 degree to the right.  Sort of like a rocking motion.

I want this done when I touch the actual sprite, not just anywhere on the screen.

As it is right now, when I touch anywhere on the screen it rotates, 360 degrees (360 degrees for testing) but every time I tap the screen I get a new sprite.

My question is one, how do I set it up so when I touch the sprite it will perform the rocking motion that I am after?  Without having a new sprite pop up each and every time I tap the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check which sprite the `UITouch` is on (by checking whether the point of touch is in each sprite's rect) and start the animation in `ccTouchesBegan` or `ccTouchesEnded` according to your requirements. You can have a look at the "TouchesTest" example included with the cocos2d.

You may implement the animation like this:

```
CCAction *action = [CCSequence actions:
                    [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.25 angle:-45],
                    [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.5 angle:90],
                    [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.25 angle:-45],
                    nil];
[theSprite runAction:action];
```